# AWS Autoscaling updating

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

You can create new Launch Configuration (updating AMI or whatever) and attach this with an existing Autoscaling Group. [Per AWS Docs:](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/change-launch-config.html) After you change the launch configuration for an Auto Scaling group, any new instances are launched using the new configuration options, **but existing instances are not affected.**

How do you force this? Meaning relaunch all new instances now (with the new AMI). Do I have to delete the existing Autoscaling Group and create a new Autoscaling Group (with new Config)? Or I simple delete existing instances (one by one manually) and then ASG relaunch with new AMI. Any best practices/gotchas?
CloudFormation has the RollingUpdate flag (not sure of this outside of CF)

Thanks

Comment: Terminating them one by one, the ASG should pick this up and launch new ones with the new configuration.

Comment: main gotcha is that if you start randomly terminating instances you can lose messages/requests or end up in an unexpected state. Depending how you application is set up.

Answer (score 1):

AWS has some OOTB solutions for this, [CloudFormation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatepolicy.html) (like you say), [Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.rollingupdates.html) (built on top of CF), and [CodeDeploy blue-green deployments](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/welcome.html#welcome-deployment-overview-blue-green) (I've not tried this).

---

Personally for our SQS polling ASG, we do a "cold deploy" i.e. only "deploy" when there are no messages to process (and hence, due a scaling policy, no instances).  It's been really effective.

A deploy can be done safely whilst there are messages, provided that you set scale-in-protection on the instance during message processing (and remove it and wait briefly before polling):

1. set desired-capacity to 0
2. wait a bit (for there to be no instances running)
3. set desired-capacity back to N.

Note: you can do this all in the console.

You can code a solution yourself that does this... but I probably wouldn't.

---

Be careful:

> simple delete existing instances (one by one manually)

Whether you can do this, or depends on whether the instances are still handling requests/processing (usually you can't simply terminate an instance without dropping service).

I recommend Elastic Beanstalk which gives a rolling update feature for free and is very easy to get started. I've not tried the CodeDeploy blue-green but it looks interesting. If you want more advanced behavior (or are already using it) look into Cloud Formation... **do not code your own solution for rolling deployments**: just use CloudFormation.

Comment: Thanks. Deleting the ASG and reattaching the new ASG does the same thing (at least in theory) - sets capacity to 0 and then deletes existing Instances, then relaunching with new ASG/Config. Regarding manual deletes - Yes I can see the pitfalls.

Comment: @Sam-T It really depends on your usecase, the issue with detaching an instance (and then presumably detaching from an ELB?) is they'll still be running , you're going to have to terminate them manually eventually. "Detaching the ASG" from what? If this is a web app, I strongly recommend Elastic Beanstalk, it's the bomb.

Comment: Actually you are not simply detaching but actually deleting old instances and simultaneously replacing (and reattaching) with new instances. Rolling Deploy's would do the same - (some nuance may be different) - CF, OpsWks, and EB all have this feature.

Comment: @Sam-T do you mean "terminates"? See also https://serverfault.com/questions/384644/how-can-i-automatically-cycle-a-new-image-in-an-aws-auto-scaling-group/843245#843245

Comment: Yes I meant Terminate

Answer (score 1):

if your issue is with "in flight" requests simply enable connection draining or increase de-registration delay of the ELB or "target groups" attached with the ASG. You can set a value up to one hour.

> When you enable connection draining, you can specify a maximum time for the load balancer to keep connections alive before reporting the instance as de-registered. The maximum timeout value can be set between 1 and 3,600 seconds (the default is 300 seconds). When the maximum time limit is reached, the load balancer forcibly closes connections to the de-registering instance.

Then you can detached old instances.

> If you detach an instance from an Auto Scaling group that has an attached load balancer, the instance is deregistered from the load balancer. If you detach an instance from an Auto Scaling group that has an attached target group, the instance is deregistered from the target group. If connection draining is enabled for your load balancer, **Auto Scaling waits for in-flight requests to complete.**

If you don't want to do any manual scaling I guess the best approach is to changing the termination policy to OldestInstance and leave the ASG as it is. When the scale-in activity happens ASG will automatically terminate the old instances.(in your case old launch config instances)

> **OldestInstance**. Auto Scaling terminates the oldest instance in the group. This option is useful when you're upgrading the instances in the Auto Scaling group to a new EC2 instance type. You can gradually replace instances of the old type with instances of the new type.